# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'size'

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network, gated-recurrent-unit

UPDATE: after looking back on this question, most of the code was unnecessary. In summary, the hidden layer of a Pytorch RNN needs to be a torch tensor. When I posted the question, the hidden layer was a tuple.

Below is my data loader.

```
from torch.utils.data import TensorDataset, DataLoader

def batch_data(log_returns, sequence_length, batch_size):
    """
    Batch the neural network data using DataLoader
    :param log_returns: asset's daily log returns
    :param sequence_length: The sequence length of each batch
    :param batch_size: The size of each batch; the number of sequences in a batch
    :return: DataLoader with batched data
    """
    
    # total number of batches we can make
    n_batches = len(log_returns)//batch_size
    
    # Keep only enough characters to make full batches
    log_returns = log_returns[:n_batches * batch_size]
    
    y_len = len(log_returns) - sequence_length
    
    x, y = [], []
    for idx in range(0, y_len):
        idx_end = sequence_length + idx
        x_batch = log_returns[idx:idx_end]
        x.append(x_batch)
        # only making predictions after the last word in the batch
        batch_y = log_returns[idx_end]    
        y.append(batch_y)    
    
    # create tensor datasets
    x_tensor = torch.from_numpy(np.asarray(x))
    y_tensor = torch.from_numpy(np.asarray(y))
    
    # make x_tensor 3-d instead of 2-d
    x_tensor = x_tensor.unsqueeze(-1)
    
    data = TensorDataset(x_tensor, y_tensor)
    
    data_loader = DataLoader(data, shuffle=False, batch_size=batch_size)
    
    # return a dataloader
    return data_loader
```

```
    def init_hidden(self, batch_size):
        ''' Initializes hidden state '''
        # Create two new tensors with sizes n_layers x batch_size x n_hidden,
        # initialized to zero, for hidden state and cell state of LSTM
        weight = next(self.parameters()).data
        
        if (train_on_gpu):
            hidden = (weight.new(self.n_layers, batch_size, self.n_hidden).zero_().cuda(),
                      weight.new(self.n_layers, batch_size, self.n_hidden).zero_().cuda())
        else:
            hidden = (weight.new(self.n_layers, batch_size, self.n_hidden).zero_(),
                      weight.new(self.n_layers, batch_size, self.n_hidden).zero_())
        
        return hidden
```

I don't know what is wrong. When I try to start training the model, I am getting the error message:

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'size'
```

Comment: Can you also provide the code where you call your model?

Comment: added to my post ... let me know if you would also like to see the training loops

Comment: what is the type of nn_input `type(nn_input)`

Comment: @Mattpats, yes that would be interesting to see as well. More precisely, what value is passed as `hidden`?

Comment: https://github.com/mattpats/GRU_time_series_regression

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue comes from the fact that `hidden` (in the `forward` definition) isn't a `Torch.Tensor`. Therefore, `r_output, hidden = self.gru(nn_input, hidden)` raises a rather confusing error without specifying exaclty what's wrong in the arguments. Altough you can see it's raised inside a `nn.RNN` function named [`check_hidden_size()`](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/e44b2b72bd4ccecf9c2f6c18d09c11eff446b5a3/torch/nn/modules/rnn.py#L220)...

I was confused at first, thinking that the second argument of `nn.RNN`: `h0` was a tuple containing `(hidden_state, cell_state)`. Same can be said ofthe second element returned by that call: `hn`. That's not the case `h0` and `hn` are both `Torch.Tensor`s. Interestingly enough though, you are able to unpack stacked tensors:

```
>>> z = torch.stack([torch.Tensor([1,2,3]), torch.Tensor([4,5,6])])
>>> a, b = z
>>> a, b
(tensor([1., 2., 3.]), tensor([4., 5., 6.]))
```

You are supposed to provide a tensor as the second argument of a [`nn.GRU`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.nn.GRU.html?highlight=gru) `__call__`.

---

*Edit* - After further inspection of your code I found out that you are converting `hidden` back again to a *tuple*... In cell [14] you have `hidden = tuple([each.data for each in hidden])`. Which basically overwrites the modification you did in `init_hidden` with `torch.stack`.

Take a step back and look at the [source code](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/e44b2b72bd4ccecf9c2f6c18d09c11eff446b5a3/torch/nn/modules/rnn.py#L251) for RNNBase the base class for RNN modules. If the hidden state is not given to the forward it will default to:

```
if hx is None:
    num_directions = 2 if self.bidirectional else 1
    hx = torch.zeros(self.num_layers * num_directions,
                     max_batch_size, self.hidden_size,
                     dtype=input.dtype, device=input.device)
```

This is essentially the exact init as the one you are trying to implement. Granted you only want to reset the hidden states on every epoch, (I don't see why...). Anyhow, a basic alternative would be to set `hidden` to `None` at the start of an epoch, passed as it is to `self.forward_back_prop` then to `rnn`, then to `self.rnn` which will in turn default initialize it for you. Then overwrite `hidden` with the hidden state returned by that RNN forward call.

To summarize, I've only kept the relevant parts of the code. Remove the `init_hidden` function from `AssetGRU` and make those modifications:

```
def forward_back_prop(rnn, optimizer, criterion, inp, target, hidden):
    ...
    if hidden is not None:
        hidden = hidden.detach()
    ...
    output, hidden = rnn(inp, hidden)  
    ...
    return loss.item(), hidden


def train_rnn(rnn, batch_size, optimizer, criterion, n_epochs, show_every_n_batches):
    ...
    for epoch_i in range(1, n_epochs + 1):
        
        hidden = None
        
        for batch_i, (inputs, labels) in enumerate(train_loader, 1):
            loss, hidden = forward_back_prop(rnn, optimizer, criterion, 
                                             inputs, labels, hidden)
            ...

    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately, I am still getting the same error message. Not sure if this helps or not, but this notebook was originally a NLP word generator. I am trying to convert it to a regression model so that instead of predicting the next word, it predicts the next number in a time series. The major difference b/w the two models being an absence of an embedding layer in the new model. Would the absence of an embedding layer possibly explain the error message?

Comment: I don't think the embedding layer is the issue. Could you provide the code for the main training loop where your GRU class is called?

Comment: I figured it would be easier to post the entire notebook and dataset to github. If you prefer to see it in stackoverflow, just let me know.
https://github.com/mattpats/GRU_time_series_regression

Comment: I think it is training properly now. Thank you very much for your help. I had a quick question though. By setting hidden=None at the beginning of each epoch, the hidden state will initialize/reset to the default hidden state provided in RNNBase code you describe. But when you say "I don't see why" when referring to this, is there a better method you're thinking of?

Comment: I'm just curious what is the reason behind keeping the hidden states in memory for all data points in the dataset. Is it something you read somewhere? I don't know the answer myself. I would not have considered doing it like that and instead just let it reset the states on each call.

Comment: It was what I saw (or thought I saw) in the examples I have seen. Being new to deep learning, I don't have a good answer.

Answer (score -1):

There should be [] brackets instead of () around 0.

```
def forward(self, nn_input, hidden):
    ''' Forward pass through the network. 
        These inputs are x, and the hidden/cell state `hidden`. '''
    
    # batch_size equals the input's first dimension
    batch_size = nn_input.size(0)
```

Comment: No, [`.size`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.size) is a function and calling `torch.Tensor.size` with an integer will return the size on that axis.